# SQL (Pervasive) - several columns to one + title columns to data

Tags: sql, pervasive

Is it possible to do a query in sql (Pervasive), to turn a several amount of columns to only one (eg.quantaties by month, to only onde column)? And that the columns titles that disapears turns into data in a new column?

I'm afraid the text is a litle confusing, but I am struggling to explain it better.

An example, turn the current database structure:

```
product_ID | price   | margin  |comission| month_A | month_B | month_C
AAAAA      |     100 |      20 |        5|      15 |      18 |      16
BBBBB      |     200 |      40 |       10|      20 |      21 |      26
CCCCC      |     300 |      60 |       15|      40 |      48 |      41
```

That I would like to change, so I can better use pivot tables in Excel:

```
product_ID |    price|margin| sales_qt| month
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|      15 |     A
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|      18 |     B
AAAAA      |     100 |    20|      16 |     C
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      20 |     A
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      21 |     B
BBBBB      |     200 |    40|      26 |     C
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      40 |     A
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      48 |     B
CCCCC      |     300 |    60|      41 |     C
```

Best regards!!!

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the table:

```
Select p.product_ID ,prices ,margin ,sale_quantity ,salemonths
From products as p inner join (    
Select product_ID  ,sale_quantity ,salemonths from products
UNPIVOT
(
    salemonths for sale_quantity in (month_A | month_B | month_C) 
)) as pp on p.product_ID = pp.product_ID
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just tryied it out, but it doesn't work... the feedback is that the command is not supported. :(